# Can an OpenShift template env variable be used in the name of a secretKeyRef?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have a template and a deployment in it, One of my deployment's env variables is a value from a secret that contains the name of the namespace that just used the template.
The secret must contain the name of the namespace, I can't change it.

I know that it is possible to use env variables as value of different env variables. Looks like this:

```
env:
  - name: MY_NAMESPACE
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        apiVersion: v1
        fieldPath: metadata.namespace
  - name: FULL_NAME
    value: ${MY_NAME}.$(MY_NAMESPACE)
```

This way, if my namespace's name is **app** and the **MY_NAME** parameter is **dan**:

```
echo $FULL_NAME
> dan.app
```

But I want to use that name as a reference to a secret name. Like this:

```
env:
  - name: MY_NAMESPACE
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        apiVersion: v1
        fieldPath: metadata.namespace
  - name: FULL_NAME_SECRET
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: ${MY_NAME}.$(MY_NAMESPACE)
        key: app_name
```

I get an event that says:

> Pod "test-0" is invalid[spec.containers[0].env[1].valueFrom.secretKeyRef.name: Invalid value: "dan.$(MY_NAMESPACE)": a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start with an alphanumeric character

Well basically it does not translate the $(MY_NAMESPACE) to the actual value of its env variable.

Answer (score 2):

The `secretKeyRef:` secret name must be a fixed string.  Variable expansion only happens in a couple of places in the pod spec (in `env:` values, `command:`, and `args:`, but nowhere else).

For your immediate problem, it may help to recognize that a Pod and any matching Secret *must* be in the same namespace.  You don't need to include the namespace name in the Secret name, and there's no way to refer to a Secret in a different namespace if you needed to.

```yaml
- name: FULL_NAME_SECRET
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: dan       # always in the same namespace
      key: app_name
```

More broadly, you can use a tool like [Helm](https://helm.sh) to fill in some of these values from templates.  These can use data known at install time to construct "fixed strings" that can be submitted to Kubernetes.

```yaml
{{/* In a Helm chart's templates/deployment.yaml */}}
- name: FULL_NAME_SECRET
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: {{ include "dan.name" . }}.{{ .Release.Namespace }}
      key: app_name
```

In this the parts in the curly braces `{{ ... }}` are expanded by Helm's template engine.  `.Release.Namespace` is the namespace into which you're installing.  `include "dan.name" .` calls a helper template that constructs the "dan" name, in a way that supports multiple installations in the same namespace.